GitLab pipeline keeps failing at `fastlane build_apk` saying it failed to install Android SDK
My GitLab pipeline is failing when it tries to run fastlane build_apk. It fails when it is trying to configure react-native-video:
> Configure project :react-native-video
useExoplayerIMA:false
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

And if I install the mentioned build-tools;30.0.3, it gives me this error:
$ sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" --include_obsolete
Warning: Dependent package with key emulator not found!
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.

I'm using a Macbook, and it is running on M1 MacOS.
Here is my gitlab.config.yml:
variables:
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
  # ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "33"
  # ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "33.0.3"
  # ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "9477386"
  SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './'
  ANDROID_KEYSTORE_FILE: '/builds/X/app/android/my-upload-key.keystore'


clean-build-job:       
  stage: build
  image: openjdk:11-jdk
  before_script:
    # # Update package list and install required packages
    - apt-get --quiet update --yes
    - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget unzip curl ruby ruby-dev build-essential libffi-dev libgmp-dev
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash -
    - apt-get install -y nodejs

    # Install Fastlane
    - gem install bundler
    - bundle install

    - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="${PWD}/android-home"
    - install -d $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
    - wget --output-document=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8512546_latest.zip
    # move to the archive at ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
    - pushd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
    - unzip -d cmdline-tools cmdline-tools.zip
    - pushd cmdline-tools
    - mv cmdline-tools tools || true
    - popd
    - popd
    - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/

    # Nothing fancy here, just checking sdkManager version
    - sdkmanager --version

    # use yes to accept all licenses
    - yes | sdkmanager --licenses || true
    - sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" --include_obsolete
    - sdkmanager "platform-tools" --include_obsolete
    - sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" --include_obsolete
    - npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
    - cd android
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - ./gradlew --stop
    - gem install bundler
    - bundle install
    - fastlane build_apk

Fastlane:
module FLAVOR
  DEV = "dev"
  STAGING = "staging"
  PRODUCTION = "production"
end

default_platform(:android)


platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Build APK"
  lane :build_apk do |options|
    gradle(
      task: "assemble",
      # flavor: FLAVOR::DEV, 
      build_type: "Release",
    )
  end


  desc "Deploy to firebase app distribution"
  lane :distribute do

    gradle(
      task: "bundle",
      # flavor: FLAVOR::DEV, 
      build_type: "Release"
    )

    
    release = firebase_app_distribution(
      service_credentials_file: "./key.json",
      app: "1:22641879258:android:5d5dffdc5b710a1f5ba774",
      testers: "xxx@gmail.com",
      android_artifact_type: "AAB",
      debug: true
    )
  end


  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    crashlytics
  
    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store
  end
end


Can you post fastlane action file?

Thanks! I've added my fastlane action code to the question.

Everything looks good except instalation failed for build-tools;30.0.3 . Can you tell me the environment you are executing. Like server or local machine.

I'm using a Macbook and it is running on M1 MacOS.

@BobSmith The question is rather what you are running the CI on. To me, it looks like you are running the build in docker with the base image openjdk:11-jdk.

@vatbub you are correct but OP is saying he is using MacBook (local machine).

@WeeLi can you try different version (30.0.2) as it is working fine on my machine and also remove flag --include_obsolete may fix your problem.

@vatbub , BobSmith Should I change the base image as well since it might affect the build?
